# TFDQuery doesn't open by params value if SQL doesn't specify the param condition

Tags: delphi, vcl, firedac, dbexpress

I have the following code for TFDQuery:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Employees';
FDQuery1.Params.CreateParam(ftString, 'Name', ptInput).Value := 'Test';
FDQuery1.Open;
showmessage(FDQuery1.RecordCount.ToString);
```

If let said Employees table got 10 records, The FDQuery1.RecordCount will return 10 instead of 1. But if i change the above code with this, it will return 1

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name=:Name';
```

Since i migrating DB Express to firedac, the previous TSQLDataSet allow me to specify SQL like this and it will return recordcount = 1 if param is specified

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
```

May i know anyway to allow it return proper result by param value even sql didn't specify the param condition. Thanks

Comment: You always need to specify params in the actual SQL text, that is how the Database engine knows which params to look for and where inside the query to use them. That was true in dbExpress, too

Comment: The fact that you got the result you were expecting without specifying the parameter(s) in your Sql maybe just a quirk of the version of DBX you are using.  You will have to get used to the change in FireDAC.

Comment: For DB Express that allow SQL without condition param can have benefit for e.g can open the dataset by either Employee's Name or Code. so i no need to change the SQL, just change the param will do

Comment: @SherlynChew that is not how SQL or dbExpress or FireDAC are meant to work, though. If it worked for you, it was a fluke, like MartynA said. Don't rely on it. Be explicit in your parameters. That is the official, documented, intended way to use parameterized queries